Typescript - generic event callback typing
I'm trying to create a generic event handler that can subscribe and broadcast. I was wondering why the callback arguments are being unioned.
I was hoping the argument would get inferred from the Event
type FooCallback = (props: { foo: string }) => void
type BarCallback = (props: { bar: number }) => void

type Events = { "foo": FooCallback[], "bar": BarCallback[] }
type EventName = keyof Events

type OnEvent = <T extends EventName>(eventName: T, callback: Events[T][number]) => void

type TriggerEvent = <T extends EventName>(
    eventName: T,
    args: Parameters<Events[T][number]>[0]
) => void


export default class Broadcast {

    private events: Events = { foo: [], bar: [] }

    constructor() {}

    on: OnEvent = (eventName, callback) => {

        // Argument of type 'FooCallback | BarCallback' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FooCallback & BarCallback'.
        this.events[eventName].push(callback)
    }

    trigger: TriggerEvent = (eventName, args) => {
        this.events[eventName].forEach(callback => {

            // Argument of type '{ foo: string; } | { bar: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ foo: string; } & { bar: number; }'.
            callback(args)
        })
    }
}


If you want to express a higher-order correlation like this in a way TS understands, you need to do so as described in ms/TS#47109, otherwise it widens to union constraints and you get the behavior from ms/TS#30581.  The approach for your example is shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplication source; if not, what am I missing?

This worked perfectly, TY @jcalz! Going through and trying to understand it now.
